# Inkscape: Force defaults to PDF

Tags: inkscape

I want to make it easier to use Inkscape. So I want the defaults to be changed to what my users expect. They use Inkscape to edit PDF files, so import should be as visually accurate as possible and saving should be in PDF.

I want import to be "Poppler/Cairo" (preferably the PDF import settings is never shown).

I want the save format to default to ".pdf" instead of ".svg", and use the defaults for PDF export (preferably the "Portable Document Format" export settings is not shown).

It would also be nice, if I could configure Inkscape to not complain when closing the window: My users do not want to save as SVG and will only be confused by this.

Can Inkscape be configured to do all of this?

(The users run Microsoft Windows 10).

Comment: The place to configure inkscape is in the preferences, but those behaviours you mentioned aren't options in there. So the answer is no. I suppose there's nothing to stop you reprogramming the software though - since Inkscape is Open Source.

Comment: This is a very "technical" question rather than "graphics related" question. I highly recommend discussing this with the developers on the dev channel: https://chat.inkscape.org/channel/team_devel

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to preserve text when using "Poppler" library; text will be converted to paths.